# Just set up Docsify on Github Pages, issues: 2 search fields, lose ability to scroll

Tags: docsify

Here's my Github repo: [My Repo](https://github.com/ANTGOMEZ/bi-docs/tree/main/docs)

When I run this through GitHub Pages: [My GH Pages site](https://antgomez.github.io/bi-docs/#/index.html)

The Sidebar displays 2 search fields. I have followed directions for setting up Search and setup seems right to me. I only want 1 search field. See index.html in repo above.

When I click on SSIS>txn I cannot scroll the page. Couldn't find anything about page scrolling in setup.

What's missing on these two items?

Answer (score 0):

> The Sidebar displays 2 search fields

This problem is caused by your `[Get Started](index.html)` in `docs/_coverpage.md`, which repeatedly accesses `index.html`.

You can change it to

```
[Get Started](/?id=docs-testgithubio)
```

to solve this problem